# MutableCollection vs RangeReplaceableCollection

Tags: swift, swift3

From [Apple's `MutableCollection` API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection):

> The `MutableCollection` protocol allows changing the values of a collection’s elements but not the length of the collection itself. For operations that require adding or removing elements, see the `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol instead.

However, `MutableCollection` requires the following subscript:

```
subscript(bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get set }
```

Doesn't this allow changing the length of the collection? For instance, couldn't we call this subscript's setter with an empty range and a non-empty subsequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you have a variable of the `MutableCollection`
type then you must call the subscript setter only with a range
and a new slice having the same length.
Some types conforming to `MutableCollection` (such as `Array`) allow a different-length replacement to insert or delete elements,
but in general, a mutable collection need not allow that.

In particular, the *default implementation* of the `MutableCollection`
subscript setter aborts with a runtime exception if the range and the
new slice do not have the same length.

**Longer answer:**

First note that you don't have to implement

```
public subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> MutableSlice<Self>
```

in your own collection because it has a default implementation in
a protocol extension. As one can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/MutableCollection.swift#L321) of that method, the subscript setter calls a

```
internal func _writeBackMutableSlice()
```

function which is implemented [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/WriteBackMutableSlice.swift#L13).
That function first copies the common number of elements from the
slice to the destination range, and then verifies that the subscript range and the new slice have the same length:

```
_precondition(
    selfElementIndex == selfElementsEndIndex,
    "Cannot replace a slice of a MutableCollection with a slice of a smaller size")
_precondition(
    newElementIndex == newElementsEndIndex,
    "Cannot replace a slice of a MutableCollection with a slice of a larger size")
```

So you cannot change the length of a `MutableCollection` via
the (default) subscript setter, and trying to do so will abort the program.

As an example, let use define a "minimal" type conforming to
`MutableCollection`:

```
struct MyCollection : MutableCollection, CustomStringConvertible {

    var storage: [Int] = []

    init(_ elements: [Int]) {
        self.storage = elements
    }

    var description: String {
        return storage.description
    }

    var startIndex : Int { return 0 }
    var endIndex : Int { return storage.count }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int { return i + 1 }

    subscript(position : Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return storage[position]
        }
        set(newElement) {
            storage[position] = newElement
        }
    }
}
```

Then replacing a part of the collection with a slice of the same length
works:

```
var mc = MyCollection([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
mc[1 ... 2] = mc[3 ... 4]
print(mc) // [0, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

But for different lengths, it aborts with a runtime exception:

```
mc[1 ... 2] = mc[3 ... 3]
// fatal error: Cannot replace a slice of a MutableCollection with a slice of a smaller size
```

Note that concrete types conforming to `MutableCollection` *may*
allow different-lengths replacement in their subscript setter,
as for example `Array` does.

Comment: So if I am to implement `subscript(bounds:)` myself (for instance if I want something else than `MutableSlice<Self>`), should I just use `assert` to make sure the number of elements match?

Comment: @TimVermeulen: I am not 100% sure, but I think you are allowed to accept a different number of elements. For example, `Array` also conforms to `MutableCollection`, but has its own setter which allows insertion  or deletion of  elements. – But any function taking a `MutableCollection` parameter must assume that only same-lengths replacements are possible.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it's only confusing because Swift's type system can't enforce that the given subsequence must have the right number of elements (and because the documentation doesn't explain it very well, either). Thanks a lot!